# Access AngularJS form in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is this the correct way of doing it? The main disadvantage is that I have to do this on each form and controller.

I have one form and want to access that form by storing a variable in a controller variable and then access it in my controller.

In my view im doing this:

```
<form name="formName">
    <div ng-init="setForm(formName);" />
</form>
```

And in my controller i got

```
$scope.setForm = function (form) {
            $scope.myForm = form;
}
```

Now after doing this I have a controller variable which is $scope.myForm.

Comment: What operations do you need to perform on the form?

Comment: I need to manage the state of few buttons via form variable. Now i could have done that easily with just simple view but I am using ngGrid to update my list of data and i got other data as well which is out of ngGrid. now in ngGrid i am using template that calls the function in my controller but i cannot access my form in those template and therefore i was thinking that what if i store my form object in my controller variable and manage the state of my form buttons within my controller.

Comment: @Dalorzo Question is very simple if you read what I am asking is How do I access form which is "formName" in my case within my controller? It is not about why. It is about how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form will automatically be available via $scope, no need to explicitly save it.

If you however need to log it at controller initialization you need to wait for Angular to have processed it.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="formName">
  </form>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    console.log($scope.formName);
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wGPKKIGjlQ6Q4GT0aAC6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for replying with positive response rather than downvoting like others. I will try your solution. Thanks once again @tasseKATT

Comment: The reason why I didn't mark it as an answer becuase If you don't use ng-controller directive on body tag it doesn't work. Moreover it not working when I doing this  "$scope.$on('dialog.confirmCancel', function () {
            $scope.formName.$pristine = true;//undefined here
            $scope.ConfigurationFactory.CancelConfirm();
        });"

Comment: If the form is outside the scope of ng-controller it will be published on the $rootScope. Regarding the dialog example that seems unrelated to the question and is probably a scope issue as well.

Comment: totally agree with you. i will raise another question for that.